# Why having extra nameserver entries in resolv.conf hinders resolving host name?

Tags: linux, dns

I have 6 nameserver entries in resolv.conf. Due to the recent changes in our network I added last 2 recently and did not bother commenting the old ones as I thought that having extra nameservers won't effect if the name is resolved or not and it will probably just take little bit more time. But without commenting out the previous 4 nameservers the names wont't resolve and I am just wondering why.

Even in **resolv.conf** manual I see:

> If there are multiple servers, the resolver library queries them in
>   the order listed. If no nameserver entries are present, the default is
>   to use the name server on the local machine. (The algorithm used is to
>   try a name server, and if the query times out, try the next, until out
>   of name servers, then repeat trying all the name servers until a
>   maximum number of retries are made.)

So I see no reason why it should not work without uncommenting the previous nameserver entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having many servers are fine as long as you understand a 'not found' **answer**, is completely different from a **failure** to communicate with the server.

Lets say you your client is configured to use Google DNS, and also pointed at internal servers for Active Directory.  Where your AD domain is not available publically.

If you client attempts to resolve your intenal domain against the public sever and got a response saying there was no results then it stops.  No failure happened.  No other servers would be queried.  Your resolver only tries another server if there is a failure.

Answer (score 2):

For Unix / Linux using the standard C library resolver code (implied by reference to `/etc/resolv.conf`), the nameserver entries are used in order with ~5 second timeout between them.  If the first 4 nameservers are non-responsive, **you have to wait a minimum of 20 seconds for every DNS query**.  This is compounded multiplicatively if you have search entries and are resolving single-label names where search list entries are appended.

Typical applications, e.g., web browser, will give up waiting for an answer after ~15 seconds, so from that perspective, the perception is "the Internet is down" even though an answer may be forthcoming.  That's the magic number here.

Bottom line, having additional nameserver references to known dead nameservers on Linux / Unix systems using straight `/etc/resolv.conf` for resolution is detrimental.